# How do I get a list of every category inside a table of books?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, maven

I have a "Books" table that looks like this:

[image]

I'm trying to make a Spring Boot app where all these books are listed, but you can filter them by category. For this, I want to show a list of every category there is so the user can click on the one they want.

What would be the better way to get this list of categories? For example, in the case of the picture above, I would like to show a list like this:

- XXX (only once)
- YYY
- ZZZ

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT category FROM Books` will get the list of unique values inside the category column, is this you're looking for? @Nono-Man

Comment: Did you consider having the categories in a separate table, and using a foreign key field to reference them?

Comment: How is the question related to `maven`?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the

@Query annotation as @lemon provided the solution

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT category FROM Books")
List<String> categories();
```

Also you can check [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query)